# implement new control type in Nop.Core

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am beginner in noCommerce 2.65. is it possible to implement a new control in

**Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.AttributeControlType**. I try to add a new control type

in Nop.Core

Please Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 - Add a control type to **Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.AttributeControlType**

2 - Modify the view **Nop.Web.View.Catalog._ProductAttributes.cshtml** for display in product page

3 - Modify the Admin part to be able to assign the type of control at the product attribute

Comment: Note that for step 2, the view to modify is now `Nop.Web.View.Product._ProductAttributes.cshtml`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the fact of change Nop.Core will require you to make the same change to each NopCommerce Update.

Comment: You'll just need to merge the affected files.